# Angular JS - Express Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am running a [MEAN](http://mean.io/) framework with express routing requests. I have two main routes to `public/` and `app`.

With the APP being an API and public being a set of web pages which reads data from the API.

```
// Setting the app router and static folder
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

I have two controllers in the public folder, **home and header.**

In the home controller I am using Angular JS to call the API and return the results.

The API allows for filtering through the use of query strings:

`$http.get('http://search?sumBoth=1&customer=' + customer)`

I would like to build up a route specific to this controller along the lines of

`http://url/customers/CustomerName`

Where `CustomerName` would be set as the customer variable

**Question**

a) Is this best done in Angular or Express?
b) Where and how do I implement such routing?

I hope this question is well received, please *comment*, if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the response of `$http.get('http://host/path?sumBoth=1&customer=' + customer)` is a *list* of search results. In that case the path should be a collection path, it's not really a best practice to have search terms in the path. Subcollection paths are pretty standard (something like `http://host/customers/search?params`, but still the specific search terms should go in the query string)

If on the contrary you expect to retrieve just one result by some identificator (provided for instance the customer name is unique) that's a different story, you should really use `http://host/customers/:identifier`.

In any case you can use angular resources, both parts of your application need to be aware of the routing. In the front-end you define an additional verb that adds the filters (or just use the standard `query` one - see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). In the back-end you need to route the call and parse the parameters. If it's a list, parse the query string and render your result array, if it's a single resource, parse the identifier, find the corresponding resource and render it back.